# MySQL: SELECT items in daterange, but also return 0 if a month doesn't have any data in the database

Tags: mysql

I have this query to get statistics from a reservation system:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(itemid) AS `num_items`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(reservation)) AS `num_reservations`,
    CONCAT(MONTHNAME(`from`),' ',YEAR(`from`)) AS `group` 
FROM 
    reserveditems 
WHERE 
    category = 11 
    AND 
    ( DATE(`from`) >= '2018-01-01' AND DATE(`until`) <= '2018-12-31') 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(`from`)
```

This gives me the right data, but I would also need to get all the months where there are no results.

Now I get this result

```
"2"    "1"    "May 2018"
"3"    "1"    "July 2018"
"11"   "8"    "October 2018"
"17"   "9"    "November 2018"
```

But I would need:

```
"0"    "0"    "January 2018"
"0"    "0"    "February 2018"
"0"    "0"    "March 2018"
"0"    "0"    "April 2018"
"2"    "1"    "May 2018"
"0"    "0"    "June 2018"
"3"    "1"    "July 2018"
"0"    "0"    "September 2018"
"11"   "8"    "October 2018"
"17"   "9"    "November 2018"
"0"    "0"    "December 2018"
```

Not only this, but the daterange can also be edited by the user, so it's possible they ask for a range from September 2017 until December 2018, so looping from 1 till 12 is not an option here.

The statistics page also lets a user decide the GROUP BY method, be it per month,year or date.
So it would be great if there was a fucntion to fill in all blank *period of time selected by user*

This could be a zero-result for the year 2016, if they should ask this data, or a zero-result for all dates in a month if there were no reservations on that day (like weekends, holidays...)

Because of this it is not possible to populate a second table with all possible date,monhts,years... to **JOIN** with this table.

If this solution is not possible with MySQL, I will have to try to solve this in my php, but I believe that MySQL would be faster than another loop over the results (especially in case of ***GROUP BY DATE(`from`)***)

Thanks for a push in the right direction!

Comment: Depending on the user input. You can create a temporary table using all the months between the input date range. And, then use that temporary table as your primary table in the query, and do a left join to consider all the months.

Comment: unrelated recommendation 1: [DATE_FORMAT(from, "%M %Y") as `group`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). Don't use `DATE(`from`)` - its already a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its possible to create temporary tables with 0 as the as the entry and join against the existing query to get a full table of results, its not a good idea.

The database is usually the hardest thing to scale on a system and the application code is the easiest. So using application code to fill out the gaps of the result is the best use of resources. Adding a column containing `YEAR(from)*12 + MONTH(from) - 1` will make it easy for the application code to detect gaps. While this is a little extra work, its using the same row data rather than creating a new table and joining against it.

Comment: Did solve it in the application. The application nog generates a daterange according to the users settings, eg. :
`    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $start,
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        $end
    );
    foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
        $dateRange[] = $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }`
(Or P1Y or P1M if another group method is checked)

Then I check the results of the database against this daterange and fill in the blanks with zeros.

Thanks and kind regards.