# PHP : I need to fill "0" on months where there is no data available from a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This seemed simple at first, but now it has become a headache.

I have a number of robberies for each month in a year, lets say 2016. My query

```
SELECT MONTH(denuncia.fecha_registro_denuncia) as mes, count(denuncia.codigo_incidente)
            FROM denuncia
            INNER JOIN incidentes ON incidentes.codigo_incidente=denuncia.codigo_incidente
            WHERE YEAR(denuncia.fecha_registro_denuncia)='".$a."' AND denuncia.codigo_incidente=0
            GROUP BY mes
```

denuncia is the same as "report to the police"

returns this:

```
+-------+--------+
| month | robber.|
+-------+--------+
|     1 |      2 |
|     2 |      2 |
|     3 |      3 |
|     4 |      2 |
|     5 |      1 |
|     8 |      2 |
|     9 |      3 |
|    10 |      1 |
|    11 |      5 |
|    12 |      2 |
+-------+--------+
```

The query is fetched as an PHP multidimensional array, using

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $b[]=$rows;
}
```

Data in array format:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 3
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 1
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 5
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 2
    )

)
```

As you can see, I am missing months 6 and 7 from my query result. Those months there were no incidents. As I searched through StackOverflow, filling the query with zeroes is somewhat a complex SQL query.

So, I have PHP to solve this. I need to output this data to a chart display library so I can view it nice and clean. The format for the input data would be:

```
[2,2,3,2,1,0,0,2,3,1,5,2]
```

So I need to put 0's on positions 6 and 7 to fill empty months with no incidents.

Thing is, my coding skills are poor. I tried some solutions but keep getting into a wall, been hours already.

Basically the algorythm is:
    -Go through the array
    -Check if month exists
    -If it doesn´t exist, echo '0,";
    -Go next position
    -Check again if month exists
    -...

Been coding for many hours and my mind can´t grasp the solution. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are your tables structure and the query that outputs the result you have showed?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296109/mysql-select-items-in-daterange-but-also-return-0-if-a-month-doesnt-have-any/53296605#53296605)

Comment: You might have luck with the MySQL COALESCE function. Feed it a list and it returns the first non-null value. So feed it a list of the `robber` column and 0. If robber is null, it returns zero.  You do this within the MySQL query, before it returns anything to PHP

Comment: @danblack I checked that question but didn´t help.

Comment: quite right, it said use PHP like you implied in the question but was light on implementation. Answer here looks sufficient.

Comment: @martincho can you attach your sql query as well

Answer (score 1):

one way you can do is you can pree fill month array with zero and set value

```
$month = array_fill_keys(range(1, 12),0); //fill month array key with month(1-12)

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  $month [$rows[0]]= $rows[1]; //check if exists set value
}
```

Comment: Nice! Now, should you use $month in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I had to use a helper variable ($indexhelp)

```
    $indexhelp=0;
    for($month_counter=1;$month_counter<=12;$month_counter++) {
        if($month_counter==$query5[$indexhelp][0]) {
                                                    echo $query5[$indexhelp][1].',';
                                                    $indexhelp++;
                                                    }
        else {echo '0,';}
        }
```

The result is added to a variable like

```
//this is javascript
chart_data=[<?php CODE HERE ?>];
```

Also, a friend told me that most logic is convenient to use in client-side, because a complex query can overload the database server.